# Conditional @Autowired based on constructor argument

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to spring and I'm trying to refactor some code, I have the following "Session.class":

```
public class Session {
    ...
    private Wallet currenetWallet;
    ...
    public Session(..., int sessionId, ...) {
        ...

        ThirdPartyToken token = context.getBean(ThirdPartyTokenDAO.class).getThirdPartyToken(sessionId);

        if (token.getExternalUser().getMerchant().getType().equals("SOAPMerchant")) {
            currenetWallet = (Wallet) context.getBean("SOAPExternalWallet", token);
        }
        else if (token.getExternalUser().getMerchant().getType().equals("JSONMerchant")) {
            currenetWallet = (Wallet) context.getBean("JSONExternalWallet", token);
        }
        else {
            currenetWallet = (Wallet) context.getBean("GuestWallet", 1000.0);
        }

        ...
    }   
}
```

I read that using context.getBean() is a bad practice, and makes the class untestable.
What would be the correct way of wiring the currentWallet according to the above?

Comment: Inject the three values, and choose which one to use based on the merchant type

Comment: Today I have 3, but what if tomorrow I'll have a dozen types, wouldn't it be a waste to wire them all ?
Although I do like this solution, it will be the easiest to implement

Comment: You actually depend on `Wallet` class, not on `sessionId`, so this is what you should be wiring and expecting in constructor. Depending on how rest of system defined, you can have a `Wallet` prototype bean, creation of which depends on `Token`, which in turn depends on that sessionId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interface `Wallet` and create implementation classes like `SOAPExternalWallet`, `JSONExternalWallet`, `GuestWallet`.
Create a factory class and then based on the type return the right implementation from factory class.

Comment: But then I don't use spring, I'd like the currentWallet field to be @autowired somehow...

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000672/spring-how-to-change-interface-implementations-at-runtime/44001051#44001051