# Dynamic injection of bean properties spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

So my problem is, I have a bean which I would like to inject dynamically based on runtime values. Lets say I have class A which has private variable B. I would like to inject my variable B (upon creation of the bean) via spring with value I got from user (for example). How can I do that ? Should I just use getBean() and then use setter method for my variable or is there any better way ?

**EDIT:**

```
@Bean 
class A {
    private int B;
    ... 
}    

main {
    context = someContext("myConfigFileWhereBeansAreDefined");
    int value = getIntFromUser();

    // I want to have myNewBean injected with "value" i got from user
    A myNewBean = context.getBean("A");
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some code snippets which explains what you are trying to do?

Comment: can your beans which you want to inject at runtime be of same type? I mean does all those beans implement same interface ?

Comment: @MatthiasSteinbauer I added some Code

Comment: @pvpkiran Yes they are instances of the same class.

Comment: see my answer here. I think it is pretty much the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000672/spring-how-to-change-interface-implementations-at-runtime/44001051#44001051

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring: how to change interface implementations at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000672/spring-how-to-change-interface-implementations-at-runtime)

Comment: You're pretty much where you need to be. It's a variation of the Command or Strategy patterns (depends on who you ask)

Comment: you can put the user desired value in a .property file and read it via the @ Value annotation, and then you can autowire the whole bean A

@Bean
class A{
@Value("${user.input.value}")
private int B;
}