# Problem in reading Spring framework doc: injecting bean to Spring at runtime

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-bean

I can not understand the following documentation sentence

> (...) the registration of new beans at runtime (concurrently with live
> access to the factory) is not officially supported and may lead to
> concurrent access exceptions, an inconsistent state in the bean
> container, or both.

I understand that it can't be injected at runtime, but previously we can read in the documentation:

> In addition to bean definitions that contain information on how to
> create a specific bean, the ApplicationContext implementations also
> permit the registration of existing objects that are created outside
> the container (by users). This is done by accessing the
> ApplicationContext’s BeanFactory through the getBeanFactory() method,
> which returns the BeanFactory DefaultListableBeanFactory
> implementation. DefaultListableBeanFactory supports this registration
> through the registerSingleton(..) and registerBeanDefinition(..)
> methods.

So how to implement this form of injection, not at the runtime. Now I'm confused.

Comment: Can you share the link where you find this information? Thanks!

Comment: [In addition to bean definitions that...](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-definition)

Comment: I believe this is relative to the dynamic registration of beans not following the regular way, e.g. [`GenericWebApplicationContext.registerBean()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html#registerBean-java.lang.Class-org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionCustomizer...-). What is exactly that you want to do?

Comment: I want to know when to inject bean, which will produce the exception described in the document. Because when I search for dynamic injection, Google is all about how to inject, and doesn't mention the exceptions mentioned in the document. Therefore, I just want to know under what circumstances there will be exceptions. Maybe I'm thinking a little too much.

Comment: Indeed you are. You usually don't dynamically register beans and even when you do, you do it using `GenericWebApplicationContext.registerBean()` and not the mentioned methods (which seems to me to be used for anything else than simply registering beans).

Comment: Well, it was a wonderful experience. Thank you from the other side of the ocean for your patient explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I might not be the right person to answer this, but I would like to give a link where it has been answered beautifully, take a look might be the similar thing you asking.

[bean injected dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105044/inject-spring-bean-dynamically)