# How to pick a bean based on a condition?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have two implementations of an interface

```
@Component
public ClassA implements SomeInterface {
}
```

```
@Component
public classB implements SomeInterface {
}
```

And then a consumer that needs an implementation of the class depending on some condition. How do I pick a particular bean?

```
@Component
public class Consumer {
  @PickTheRightBean(if(condition) then pick SomeClassA else pick SomeClassB) \\ how do I do this?
  private final SomeInterface myBean;
}
```

I tried `@Conditional` annotation, but it still ends up picking the wrong bean.

Comment: What condition do you have?

Comment: `@Conditional(MyCondition.class)`

Comment: have you checked this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105044/inject-spring-bean-dynamically

Comment: `@Conditional` doesn't work for auto wiring, you can place it on `ClassA` and `ClassB` or define bean via `@Bean` using `@Conditional`

Comment: Must be by injection ? If not,

    @Autowired 
    Context context; 
    
    SomeInterface some = cond ? 
                context.getBean(ClassA.class) : 
                context.getBean(ClassB.class);

Comment: @PeterMmm Yea that's what I thought - Spring doesn't offer this out of the box. One has to implement the logic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only feasible way to achieve what you want IMO, is to get rid of the annotation `@Component` on Consumer class so that it becomes

```
public class Consumer {
  
  private final SomeInterface myBean;
}
```

and you register it using your custom logic in a `configuration` class

```
 @Configuration
 public class MyConfiguration{

 @Bean
 public Consumer consumer(ClassA classA, ClassB classB) {

   Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
   if (your condition here){
        consumer.setMyBean(classA);
   } else {
        consumer.setMyBean(classB);
   }
   return consumer;
 }

}
```